# Hessian on non-critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature, hessian-matrix

Hessian matrices can be used in the second partial derivative test to determine whether a stationary point is a maximum, a minimum, or a saddle.

Can Hessians also be used to gain insight into non-stationary points? I.e., if a random point in a high-dimensional space is taken, and the Hessian of a function is calculated for that point, would Hessian capture local curvature information? Would the eigenvalues still convey a similar meaning?

Comment: Yes, there is essentially the same Information in the Hessian for all points. But if the gradient is not zero, it dominates the second derivatives.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42, If the gradient dominates the second derivatives, and it is non-zero, but the eigenvalues of a Hessian are all positive/all negative, can we make conclusions regarding the shape of the function locally? I.e., not a minimum, but... a basin of some sorts?.. I am trying to understand at what point the conclusions will become erroneous.

Comment: What does the second derivative of a function of one variable tell you about it at non-critical points?

Comment: Well, for a trivial y=x^2 example, it tells me that the function is convex, and not much beyond that. I guess concavity/convexity information can still be extracted. Thanks!